# Objective-C getting: error: expected selector for Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to make a simple http request method but when comping I'm getting this error:

```
 Compiling file main.m ...
In file included from main.m:1:
./HttpManager.h:4:2: error: expected selector for Objective-C method
-<NSURL*> getUrlContent:(NSString) url;
~^
main.m:11:17: warning: instance method '-getUrlContent:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
        NSURL *myURL = [pHttpManager getUrlContent:@"http://www.cnn.com"];
```

My simple source codes:

**HttpManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HttpManager:NSObject
-<NSURL*> getUrlContent:(NSString) url;
@end
```

**HttpManager.m**

```
#import "HttpManager.h"

@implementation HttpManager


-<NSURL*> getUrlContent:(NSString) url
{
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    return myURL;
}
#end
```

**main.m**

```
#import "HttpManager.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

    HttpManager* pHttpManager;
    pHttpManager  = [[HttpManager alloc] init];
    NSURL *myURL = [pHttpManager getUrlContent:@"http://www.example_site.com"]; 
    NSString *myHomePage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL
                            encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding error: NULL];

    NSLog(@"%@", myHomePage);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-(NSURL*) getUrlContent:(NSString*) url
{
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
return myURL;
}
```

And we are u using <> instead of ()? replace them also.